# iOS10 - Corner Radius is not working right with border

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios10

I've a `UIViewController` and I'm displaying it as **UIModalPresentationPopover**. It had its corner radius set to 10.0 and border width to 1.0.

```
- (void)viewWillLayoutSubviews {
  [super viewWillLayoutSubviews];     

  self.view.layer.borderWidth = 1.0f;
  self.view.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0f;
  self.view.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
}
```

It is not showing any border along corner radius  and it is giving a weird effect. It was working fine before iOS10. What should I do to solve this problem?

**Edit:** The screenshots are as
[image]

If i add 2 pixel border then still 1 pixel is missing from View
[image]

Comment: pl. try [self.view setClipsToBounds:YES]; and remove  self.view.layer.masksToBounds = YES;

Comment: @KetanP already cliping

Comment: Can you show your screen shot?

Comment: @Hoa ok sure i will upload it in a min

Comment: @Hoa screens uploaded

Comment: Try to put your codes to viewDidLayoutSubViews instead of viewWillLayoutSubViews.

Comment: I tried @Hoa doesnt works

Comment: It's strange. Try also to use UIClearColor for your content background in the pop-up, and also use UI debug in XCode 7/8 to know which uiview layer overlapses your border.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i Solved my Problem by following code

```
if(SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(@"10.0")){
    self.view.superview.layer.cornerRadius = 15.0f;
}
```

I did set the view corner radius to **10.0** so **15.0** was exact value at which the **superview** wont meddle with its **subview** corner radius and borders to show it as blur or 1 pixel less.

**Edit:** Custom created UIViewController if animated might need to implement above code after it has finished animating.

Answer (score 8):

Your code is good but it is missing one line,

```
view.clipsToBounds = true
```

Set this line and run again.

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 4):

New one thing into XCode8 we can't directly set the `cornerRadius` of the `layer`.

When you want to apply `cornerRadius` of `UIView` need to add one line of code before applying `cornerRadius`.

> yourButton.layoutIfNeeded()

Example into Objective C.

```
[yourButton layoutIfNeeded];
yourButton.layer.cornerRadius = yourButton.frame.size.height/2;
[[yourButton layer] setBorderWidth:2.0f];
```

Example into Swift3

```
self.layoutIfNeeded()
yourButton.layer.cornerRadius = self.frame.height / 2.0
yourButton.layer.borderWidth = 2.0
```

Comment: @Are you try into XCode8?

Comment: thank you, it worked for me. My problem was changing the cornerRadius of an imageView nested inside a custom cell. The change was made in awakeFromNib method. It seems that as of swift 3, before layout is performed all frames start with (0, 0, 1000, 1000).